# Map WooCommerce Product to Category in Database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, import, woocommerce

I am trying to map a WooCommerce product to a category in my Database. I have a Cronjob which imports a list of products in my database and I achieved everything by now, only the category is a problem.

I imported the category in wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy,
mapped the product in wp_terms-relationships to the category,
changed the count in wp_term_taxonomy and the meta_value in wp_termmeta

Now the product shows up in my backend with the right category:
[Product has the right category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WAAa.png)

If I click on Products > Categories I see that one product is mapped to the category:
 [Category count is 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6YLg.png)

If I click on the "1" under count I see the product, which is mapped to the category.

So far so good. BUT if I open the category in frontend, I can't see the product - the category is empty.

I import products with normal SQL Queries not with WordPress-functions. Here an example:

```
$statement = $wp->prepare("INSERT INTO wp_terms(term_id, name, slug)  VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
$success = $statement->execute(array($IdTermCatENG, $name, $slug));
echo ($success == true ? "+" : "-")." Inserting 'Category'<br>";
```

I created a category by hand in the backend just to see, how the category is saved in the database and did everything like it should be, but no hope...

Maybe you have an idea, how I could achieve that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For terms as categories related to products ('taxonomy'='product_cat') in woocommerce, 5 tables are concerned: wp_terms, wp_termmeta, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_woocommerce_termmeta. Check if your SQL query is populating correctly all the needed ones.

Comment: Are you using any plugin? This plugin has the option to import all product  categories with hierarchy. https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/